# How to use the dbDacFx Provider in Web Deploy for a delta db deployment

Tags: windows, deployment, web, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

I'm struggling to the maximum trying to get DB deployment done from a remote client.

Let me fire you some details.

Problem

- System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'ClassName' was not found.
- Occurs during a publish to the remote IIS server from Visual studio 2012.

Server

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- IIS 7.5
- SQL SERVER 2012 Express

What goes wrong

- I select publish on my web application (within visual studio 2012 / windows 8 pro)
- I publish my web application no problem to my remote web server (confirmed web page deployed and is accessible from www).
- I open publish again, this time selecting DB publish.
- Exception occurs on the server, message is propagated to client. 
  => application publishing is fine, just not DB.

What i've tried

- Every guide, faq, step by step guide I can find online.
- I've uninstalled and re-installed all the deployment packages for IIS (DAC framework, Web Deployment 3, Web deployment tools 2.1 - server)
- Re install all client side DAC libraries on client.
- Uninstall, re-install, rebooting, punching my keyboard and monitor (not my main DELL ultrasharp 24..just my 21" acer thing).

Nothing is helping (except the keyboard punching..which made me feel slightly relieved), i've just spent 10 hours, no joy. Service Delegation entries are setup for the correct DAC based provider.

Seems to be some fundamental problem, based on my understanding, an assembly is being reflected on, and is expecting to have a member called 'ClassName'..but it doesn't exist..i.e....the assembly must not be in sync with the consumer.

But there are no clear guidelines on line to confirm/ diagnose this..and nothing in the exception log except for this error (see below).

I've found a similar post on here with the same exception message, except the guys suggestions didn't help for me at all - tried them.

Please help, i've turned to chocolate biscuits and plain hambugers to drown out  the pain...i'll need to drown myself again tomorrow at the gym (this time in sweat).

Thank you,

Karl

A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID '7dd5089d-4e51-4f27-aecc-c8044754a01e'. Request Timestamp: '10/11/2012 8:55:08 PM'. Error Details:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'ClassName' was not found.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement(String name, Type& foundType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetString(String name)
   at System.Exception..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Base64EncodingHelper.DeserializeHelper(BinaryFormatter formatter, Byte[] buffer)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Base64EncodingHelper.Deserialize(String str, Exception& handledException)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SerializationHelper.Deserialize(String str)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.ProcessExeOutput()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.RunExecutableAsync(String exeName, String arguments, Int32 waitInterval, Int32 retryAttempts)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)

Comment: Please note it is 'getting' to the database, as previously there were errors stating the user did not have permissions. I fixed that permission error, then this occurs....